# Bash args in python

Tags: python, bash, args

I need to run a code like this

```
dk=$(python -c "import hashlib; hashlib.sha256('$1' + 'salt').hexdigest()");
echo $dk
```

But it's like the '$1' is not working using 'python -c'.
How to do ? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? What results do you get? What result would you expect?

Comment: I added a echo $1 before the python and the output is : "lol" ( I chosen "lol" as password ).

What I call "is not working" is that I expected that bash take my argument, then use it in the python function.
The function make a sha256 salted password using a salt.
But the actual output is a blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `print` to print the hex digest to stdout:

```
import hashlib; print hashlib.sha256('$1' + 'salt').hexdigest()
```

So the shell command becomes:

```
$ dk=$(python -c "import hashlib; print hashlib.sha256('$1' + 'salt').hexdigest()")
$ echo $dk
532b86a29eae4a625bac7c2f0208a58b5ff08e65780917d54e027d927bc92381
```

Note that this uses the value of `$1` in the parent's environment. If you wanted to pass a value as a command line argument you could modify the command to:

```
$ dk=$(python -c "import sys; import hashlib; print hashlib.sha256(sys.argv[1] + 'salt').hexdigest()" argument)
$ echo $dk
7353bc6a6fcee8b3c908bdaed02b49e6140818a0dcaf37507451b23ae6952687
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! Exactly what I wanted :D